# How to perform data lineage using Erwin

Tags: database, erwin

Data lineage is defined as a kind of data life cycle that includes the data's origins and where it moves over time. This term can also describe what happens to data as it goes through diverse processes. Data lineage can help with efforts to analyze how information is used and to track key bits of information that serve a particular purpose.

I want to know if there is a specific way to perform data lineage using Erwin. I have searched but could not find a place where it clearly says how to perform data lineage. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the Table editor and then "Where Used" I don't believe there is... it's not going to build the traditional flow chart that other lineage tools create.

Answer (score 1):

Erwin have the ability to natively see this data lineage using 2 different features.
first Design layer. Allow a conceptual/logical model to be drive to another logical or physical model.

Or

Go to your ERwin model properties and make sure that you are supporting the data movement properties capabilities of ERwin. This can be combined with the dimensional features of the ERwin modeling tool.

Once have done this. You will have the ability to go and properly document data movement rules attached to certain tables and in the column properties of the table, the is now the ability to add source to target mapping.  The source to target mapping can to use to add content to the answer provided earlier. Looking at the "Where used" properties of a table.

The data lineage however in the are report that provide source to target mapping.  Comment of the mapping can be added.

To see this graphically, you will need the new CA web portal.  Once the model is publish to portal.  Model connections are created and additional semantic, data and other lineage information are now visible graphically.  This however is another product in the ERwin solution Suite.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Data Movement option under General Model Properties
Will allow you to specify the source table/field and transformation rule for every attribute in your model.
This the only known Erwin option to establish source-to-target lineage for documentation purpose.

Ref :
https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20%20Data%20Modeler%20r7%203%2011-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/ERwin%20Online%20Help/Set_General_Model_Properties.html

Hope this helps.